# How to specify two variables on bash command line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example, I can do this:

```
 ENV=dev ruby script.rb
```

But how can I do this?

```
USER=aa PASS=bb ruby script.rb
```

I cannot use this:

```
export USER=aa
export PASS=bb
ruby script.rb
```

I have to do it in one line

Comment: `USER=aa PASS=bb ruby script.rb` works as expected. why did you think that it does not work?

Comment: PASS is empty in script

Comment: @Sato, try `USER=aa PASS=bb env | egrep 'USER|PASS'`, and you'll see both `USER` and `PASS` set. Whatever's going wrong is going wrong inside your ruby environment; the shell is doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: If you want to demonstrate otherwise, provide a complete demonstrator someone can copy-and-paste *inside the question itself*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, every Bourne shell allows any number of name=value pairs preceding the command to establish the environment.  Bash certainly does.

```
$ foo=foo bar=bar env | grep -E 'foo|bar'
foo=foo
bar=bar
```